# Not able to access nested JSON values after sending through socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sockets, websocket

I'm writing a Node.JS code which acts as an intermediate between JavaScript client and Google DialogFlow. My problem is, when I try to echo the JSON object response to the client through a web socket connection, the nested values always read as null.

My JSON Object:

```
 {
   responseId: 'xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx',
   recognitionResult: null,
   queryResult: {
     fulfillmentMessages: [ [Object] ],
     outputContexts: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     queryText: '21',
     speechRecognitionConfidence: 0,
     action: 'age',
     parameters: { fields: [Object] },
     allRequiredParamsPresent: true,
     fulfillmentText: 'All right!',
     webhookSource: '',
     webhookPayload: null,
     intent: {
       inputContextNames: [],
       events: [],
       trainingPhrases: [],
       outputContexts: [],
       parameters: [],
       messages: [],
       defaultResponsePlatforms: [],
       followupIntentInfo: [],
       name: 'Intent name',
       displayName: 'Default Intent',
       priority: 0,
       isFallback: false,
       webhookState: 'WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED',
       action: '',
       resetContexts: false,
       rootFollowupIntentName: '',
       parentFollowupIntentName: '',
       mlDisabled: false
     },
     intentDetectionConfidence: 1,
     diagnosticInfo: null,
     languageCode: 'en',
     sentimentAnalysisResult: null
   },
   webhookStatus: { details: [], code: 0, message: '' },
   outputAudio: <Buffer >,
   outputAudioConfig: {
     audioEncoding: 'OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_OGG_OPUS',
     sampleRateHertz: 0,
     synthesizeSpeechConfig: null
   }
 }
```

I'm trying to access the name value of intent. I also need to pass all the other values as well.

My Web Socket code:

```
const ws = require('ws');

const wss = new ws.Server({ noServer: true });

function onConnect(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function (newMessage) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

(I've trimmed out parts that are irrelevant)

Comment: JSON format is incorrect. 

a wrong one:
```
{
  x: 20
}
```
a correct one:

```
{
  "x": 20
}
```

Comment: @Popeye the JSON comes from google, so I don't have  much control over it

Comment: is it possible that your data is not a javascript object, rather string?

Comment: Where does `data` come from? That part is relevant.

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev Data comes from Dialogflow API. `data` is the JSON I provided at the top.

Comment: Right, but in what format? Buffer, string, object, array... I don't see it in the code, just where it is used.

Comment: If I run`JSON.stringify(data)` using the JSON you provided, it works fine, so `data` must not be what you think.

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev Object format.

Comment: Do you have the Client-side [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)?

Comment: @StackSlave Yes, I do have a client side WS.